# Multiple pages on one with different HTML

Tags: php, css, html

I am a bit confused on how this may be achieved. I have a website that I have coded already with static HTML/CSS and I am trying to incorporate it into wordpress. The challenge though is that the website is single page index.html file with 4 "sections". I want each section to be a page that can be accessed by anyone to edit the content at a later date. I have figured out how to get the page to loop out my four pages through other stackoverflow resources, however the challenge I am facing is the HTML markup.

Is there a way to make each section loop out different HTML for that given section? Each section is formatted differently.

For example, section one may have 4 divs, while section three has one div and it is a different ID. The current loop only will loop out the same kind of HTML.

I've read about custom fields which I plan to incorporate for specific parts of the sections, but from a wider scope, I can't figure out how to get different HTML markup for each section first.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages();
  foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
  $title = $page_data->post_title;
$slug = $page_data->post_name;

echo "<div id='$slug'>";
echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
echo $content;
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attack the `get_pages();` function another way to sort your code better and read it better as well, take a look at [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) for more info.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title', // sorting by alphabetical order of post title for example
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',    // edit this parameter instead of $pages = get_pages('include=2,4,5,8');
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => -1,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); //edit whatever parameter you need to get what you need (sort_column to select which column to sort by), this list shows all parameters!!!

$pages = get_pages($args); 

    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
        $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;

        if( $page_data->ID == 2 ){ //format 1
            get_template_part( 'content-1', get_post_format() ); //get post template from content-1.php
            }
        elseif( $page_data->ID == 4 ){ //format 2
            get_template_part( 'content-2', get_post_format() ); //get post template from content-2.php
            }

        }
?>
```

I presented a variation for the content of the `if` statement in case the code that displays each section gets too big, you can simply break it into other files to control it with ease and make it more readable. More usage about the `get_template_part();` function refer to [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part).

Comment: Why is it that if I pass nothing as a parameter to include ('include' ==> '') and then in the if statement, for testing purposes just have 

    if( $page_data->ID = 2 ){ //format 1
    echo $content;
            }

It echos out every page I have. However if I put 2 as the parameter in the include, and change the if statement to ->ID == 3. Page 2 still shows?

Comment: I see why, it needed to be $page_data->ID == 2, not = 2

Comment: Ok, I'll correct that on my answer, but don't forget I posted all the possible arguments in the `$args` array, so you can clear whichever you aren't using.

Comment: This is a great help, I'm on my way so far to building my static one page now into wordpress. I'll let you know how the rest goes!

Comment: @James By the way I'm also trying to build a "one page" template but based on categories if you want to take a peek at the loop, it might give you ideas [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99492/how-to-create-a-category-and-sub-category-sorted-blogroll-with-all-posts)

Answer (score 1):

well you can have conditional if else statements to output different html for different pages, based on page id.
But first modify your get_pages to fetch only those 4 pages(or 'sections' as you are calling it). The current code will show all the pages that are there on your website. I am pretty sure you don't want that. so instead of just

```
$pages = get_pages();
```

you should do something like

```
$pages = get_pages('include=2,4,5,8');
```

where 2,4 etc.. are the id of desired pages.
Then, you can modify your code to check for page id and output html accordingly

```
if( $page_data->ID == 2 ){
//format 1
echo "<div id='$slug'>";
echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
echo $content;
echo "</div>";
}
elseif( $page_data->ID == 2 ){
//format 2
echo "<div id='page-". $page_data->ID ."'>";
echo "<div class='page-title'>$title</h2>";
echo $content;
echo "</div>";
}
//... and so on
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of logical sense reading this response. I have a few questions though. Is there a way to make the pages show in a given order? I ordered them under the admin side but that did not seem to effect anything. Also when I try to put your code in, nothing appears on the page. When I add $pages = get_pages('include=2,4,5,8'); mixed with my orignal code, it shows just those pages but the if part of yours simply shows blank when I test it.