# How can I automatically display a visual archive of subcategory posts [and thumbnails] separate from Parent category?

Tags: categories

I am using a Wordpress theme, Uncode, that uses the WP Bakery Page Builder / Visual Composer. Here is a brief how-to video that shows the module as part of the theme to query each archive type. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8_H2neBRRA

I want to create categories and subcategories within the Posts section to differentiate the posts: https://toddsines.com/direction/ <-- lists all Direction spots

https://toddsines.com/direction/fashionfilms/ <-- Should list all Fashion films I directed, but instead throws a 404 error.

I tried looking into tweaking the Uncode child theme functions.php, category.php, archive.php and category-$slug.php, as well as some specific subcategory PHP files to show just the results of 1 Subcategory instead of the Parent category to no avail.

I tried to follow this and it is way over my head [I'm a director/photographer/musician, not really a developer, but will get my hands dirty when necessary]

[How to create a category and sub-category sorted blogroll with all posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99492/how-to-create-a-category-and-sub-category-sorted-blogroll-with-all-posts?rq=1)

```
<?php
/* template name: Posts by Category! */
get_header(); ?>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php
            // get all the categories from the database
            $cats = get_categories(); 

                // loop through the categries
                foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                    // setup the cateogory ID
                    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
                    // Make a header for the cateogry
                    echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
                    // create a custom wordpress query
                    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=100");
                    // start the wordpress loop!
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <?php echo '<hr/>'; ?>

                    <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
                <?php } // done the foreach statement ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I stuck the above in a file called archive-postsbycategory.php and I'm still getting 404 errors. I am sure that is incorrect but I also don't know what is correct syntax.

Additionally, I saw that the developer in the StackExchange link tried to automatically create archives of categories without having to hard-code each and every subcategory, because they may expand, shrink or be reorganized. So making custom content blocks within the theme's post/page builder seems redundant given that the work is being categorized in the post as each post is made. I am surprised that this functionality is not standard practice. I tried looking for plugins and I clearly cannot find the right flavor of queries or something that does not break the Uncode theme to achieve my desires. I would prefer an elegant example — don't we all?

The end result would be like this: A Finder window, with an index of large thumbnails and captions below, but styled similar to this: https://toddsines.com/direction/

When I click the dropdown to https://toddsines.com/direction/fashionfilms/

I should only see fashion films contained within the Direction category.

I DO NOT want a text list.

I want it to look exactly like the examples above and in the YouTube clip — aka styled buttons with animations, CSS-styled text overtop regenerated thumbnails from the media library, etc.

I have fought with WP for the last 4 days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress should automatically be displaying archives for each category using files from your theme (or child theme - more on that lower down) from the [file hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/).

The specific order is:

1. category-slug.php
2. category-ID.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

It sounds like you need to create or edit your category.php file unless you have ID or slug based customisations. Check the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) if in doubt.

As for your 404 errors, check the permalinks section in your admin area. Sometimes (especially after making changes) it needs you to hit save there to flush through the changes.

### Further reading

#### Customising archives

[This guide](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/customizing-wordpress-archives-categories-terms-taxonomies/) goes into detail about customising archives but it is just one of many tutorials on the web.

#### Child themes

A child theme is a way to make a theme based on another theme without updates to the parent undoing all your work. I assume that this is what you have done in customising your theme. If not Google the subject because there is a lot of good content already written about creating a child theme.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Matthew. I think the problem is honestly with the theme's query, to display the results in a Content Block, which is then embedded into the Archive Page's Content section. It circumvents "normal" WP conventions by allowing you to query *the whole database* when what I really want is for it to just follow WP archive display practices according to the archive. 

site.com/parentcategory/subcategory/postname is written as just
site.com/postname 

Which isn't what I'm after. 

I think I should rephrase the question, and instead try to rewrite the Permalinks.

Comment: https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-permalinks-url-rewriting/

Would it be easier to do the following? Create the "Commercials" page using the theme's Content Block / Query / Archive post. 

Name the page with the permalink https://toddsines.com/commercials

Then use some kind of rewrite trickery to make https://toddsines.com/direction/commercials display the commercials page as it is shown above? 

If I wasn't using the theme your aforementioned ideas would work. But because I want it to look specifically like the rest of the theme this is the only way I can make it look the way I want.